# Paraphrase the the sentence, or just tell me the meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Think of those fleeting moments when you look out of an aeroplane window and realize that, **regardless of the indignities of commercial air travel**, you are flying, higher than a bird, an Icarus safe from the sun. Now think of your laptop, thinner than a manila envelope, or your cellphone nestled in the palm of your hand. Take a moment or two to wonder at those marvels. You are the lucky inheritor of a dream come true.

----Anyone can paraphrase the bold part of the sentence please?! I really don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

The word "regardless" means, in this context, despite the current situation.

So the quoted text is saying that air travel isn't the most pleasant possible experience one could imagine. Security at the airport. Over booked planes. Boredom on the plane on long flights. Seats that are ever narrower and have ever less leg room. That 9 year old in the seat behind you that insists on kicking your seat every single second of the flight.

So, even though air travel has problems, it is still a marvel.

Answer (score 1):

***Regardless of the indignities of air travel*** simly means "without paying any regard to all the getting to and from the airport, ticketing hassle, queues, baggage protocols, passports, security checks, having to sit in narrow seats, airline food, tiny cubicle toilets etc"